# TraitsUI CheckListEditor with default selections?

Tags: python, enthought, traits, traitsui

I'm using a CheckListEditor [(source](https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/traitsui/editors/check_list_editor.py), [docs](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/TUIUG/factories_basic.html)) to present a list of options to users for configuring a simulation.  By using the `custom` View options, it displays these selections as checkboxes.  What I can't figure out is how to set some pre-selected or pre-checked boxes?  IE the default settings for the simulation.

```
from traits.api import *
from traitsui.api import *

class Test(HasTraits):          
    foo = List(editor=CheckListEditor(values = ['a','b','c']))

    traits_view = View(Item('foo', style='custom'))

Test().configure_traits()
```

Below is a SS of the output.  How would I initialize this with say `a` and `b` checked?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to specify the default value of the `List`.  That is, change this:

```
    foo = List(editor=CheckListEditor(values = ['a','b','c']))
```

to

```
    foo = List(editor=CheckListEditor(values = ['a','b','c']), value=['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: Thank you!  May I ask, do you have it set that tags like traits/traitsui/enthought will trigger alerts to you via email or something?  I figured this thread was lost in the heap by now.

Comment: No, I just browse those tags now and then.